# Flask-SQLAlchemy Constructor

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

in the Flask-SQLAlchemy tutorial, a constructor for the User model is defined:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
```

for a table with two columns, that might be acceptable, but what if I have tables with 10+ columns? do constructors **have** to be defined each time I define a new model?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

In most cases not defining a constructor in your model class gives you the correct behavior.

Flask-SQLAlchemy's base model class (which is also SQLAlchemy's declarative base class) [defines a constructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#create-an-instance-of-the-mapped-class) that just takes `**kwargs` and stores all the arguments given, so it isn't really necessary to define a constructor.

If you do need to define a constructor to do some model specific initialization, then do so as follows:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # do custom initialization here
```

By letting the base class handle the `**kwargs` you free yourself from the complexity of initializing the fields of the model.

Comment: Great answer. Your blog, book(s) and SO answers make flask usable for me. On this question, would it be possible to upgrade the answer slightly for the more complicated and I think common case of using a user mixin? For example I am using `flask_security.UserMixin`. I think that will be more useful than me posting a virtually identical question.

Answer (score 20):

I know this is a little old but regardless it should be useful for someone else with similar issue. 
If you encounter the "TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" - it means you need to provide the keywords when creating the objects to add to your database like so:

`db.session.add(User(username='myname',email='my@email',password='mypassword'))`.

It is quite common to come across this small issue...but difficult to spot.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can write the constructor however you want, you'll just need to initialize each field before trying to save the object in the database.

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...

user = User()
user.username = 'foo'
user.email = 'foo@bar.com'
db.session.add(user)
```

You can initialize parameters in the constructor this way as well.

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = generate_random_password()
        self.last_login = None
```

Comment: thanks Michael. my problem is, that when I omit the model constructor I get this: "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)". any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Are you passing values in when you construct an object?

Comment: I am doing: db.session.add(User('myname','my@email','mypassword')).

Comment: And your constructor takes a username, email and password?

Comment: yes, exactly:

def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password