# Flask-SQLAlchemy Constructor Confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Once again this code is from Miguel Grindberg's book "Flask Web Development". In models.py we have 3 classes, a Role class which has 3 roles (User, Moderator, Administrator), a User class (id, username, email, role_id, password_hash, confirmed), and a Permsission class (code below). In chp 9 page 114, he adds some code to the User class to check if the email address belongs to the admin and if so adds it to the role. If not, the user is added to the default role (user). . .

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    if self.role is None:
        if self.email == current_app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN']:
            self.role = Role.query.filter_by(permissions=0xff).first()
    if self.role is None:
        self.role = Role.query.filter_by(default=True).first()
```

My question is, why do we need a constructor for this code? A constructor isn't used in any other part of the file (full code below), so why do we need one now? I've looked at this question on Stack ([Flask-SQLAlchemy Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460339/flask-sqlalchemy-constructor)) which shed some light on the subject as far as the base class constructor, but NOT why I need a constructor at all for this piece of code. .Again, THANKS for any help.

```
class Permission:
    FOLLOW = 0x01
    COMMENT = 0x02
    WRITE_ARTICLES = 0x04
    MODERATE_COMMENTS = 0x08
    ADMINISTER = 0x80


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    default = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

@staticmethod
def insert_roles():
    roles = {
        'User': (Permission.FOLLOW |
                 Permission.COMMENT |
                 Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES, True),
        'Moderator': (Permission.FOLLOW |
                      Permission.COMMENT |
                      Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES |
                      Permission.MODERATE_COMMENTS, False),
        'Administrator': (0xff, False)
    }
    for r in roles:
        role = Role.query.filter_by(name=r).first()
        if role is None:
            role = Role(name=r)
        role.permissions = roles[r][0]
        role.default = roles[r][1]
        db.session.add(role)
    db.session.commit()

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Role %r>' % self.name


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.role is None:
            if self.email == current_app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN']:
                self.role = Role.query.filter_by(permissions=0xff).first()
            if self.role is None:
                self.role = Role.query.filter_by(default=True).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

In typical OO lingo a closer "constructor" equivalent in Python would be a `__new__` method rather than `__init__`. Although to be frank that does not map very well to Python concepts really: you have `__new__` method for object creation and `__init__` is typically used for initialization. So maybe this is a "split" constructor?

Anyway, `.__init__` is where in Python we typically adjust instance's attributes, so `super()` method above does initialization for `User` superclass and remainder of child class's `__init__` does initialization for the child class. You have to do things like say implementing some logic that depends keyword attributes, etc, somewhere - either you do it outside the class (which violates principle of encapsulation) or you do it in some method inside a class or instance. `__init__` is typical and I'm rather astonished thinking why someone would NOT use it.

You also list some SQLAlchemy object with things like declarative `__tablename__` class attribute that do not use `__init__`. Well, `zzzeek` is a black magician doing wicked and morally controversial stuff so he has risen above peon's `__init__` methods that us mere mortals use every day. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I'm still a little confused. So, you're saying he should've used a constructor for the rest of the class, ie `def __init__(self):` then `self.email=email` etc? I also noticed in the Flask-SQLAlchemy docs quickstart, they use a constructor like this, yet they do NOT call the base class constructor, which also confuses me. I thought it was 'mandatory' to call the base class constructor when using your own constructor in a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
if self.role is None:
    if self.email == current_app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN']:
        self.role = Role.query.filter_by(permissions=0xff).first()
if self.role is None:
    self.role = Role.query.filter_by(default=True).first()
```

I think there have some kind of preprocessing and that superclassing is for ealrier checking. So everytime when we querying a User this check will happen.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer cyberra. ALthough I'm still not sure why we need a constructor to add this code to begin with.

Comment: Then try to write without this constructor and see - how it looks and how difficult to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new User instance is created, the constructor assigns a role to that User instance. If this constructor wasn't created, then every time a User instance was created, you would have to assign it a role somewhere else (such as in a route). But that assumes that User instances will be created only within your app if a form is submitted and/or a route is called. This can be messy and leaves holes for some Users to have a None role, which if your app isn't expecting could let users perform actions on the site they are not allowed to do.

By default Flask-SQLAlchemy uses SQLAlchemy's base class defines the constructor (per [Flask-SQLAlchemy Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460339/flask-sqlalchemy-constructor)). This is why you can create models in Flask-SQLAlchemy without ever having to create a constructor, because it is created by default.

So if you wanted to do something specific in the creation of a model instance (such as assign a value to a column based on some logic), then you need to create the constructor yourself but can use `super(MODEL, self).__init__(**kwargs)` to save you time in typing out the N columns in that model, since super is inheriting the base class.