# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How do I call an instance method on a model instance before committing it to the database?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model that I would like to initialize, e.g. `SomeModel(name='george', password='whatever')`.

Before committing this to the database, I want to call another method (we'll call it `gen_password_hash`) to create a hashed version of the password, and set it as an attribute on the model instance.

So I want this to happen after instantiation, but before being committed to the database.

**Update**

I wanted to see if I could accomplish this by defining an `__init__` function on my model.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.set_pass(kwargs.pop('password'))
    super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.generate_email_address_confirmation_token()
```

This is the traceback I get when trying to drop/recreate tables among other things to reset my app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gg.cli
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/gg/cli/__init__.py", line 183, in <module>
    reset_all()
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/gg/cli/__init__.py", line 164, in reset_all
    load_test_data()
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/gg/cli/__init__.py", line 51, in load_test_data
    admin=True)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 411, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/gg/users.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.generate_email_address_confirmation_token()
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/gg/users.py", line 71, in generate_email_address_confirmation_token
    token.update(self.email_address.encode() + current_app.secret_key + \
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/blaine/freelance/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 51, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve
this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

I used [this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460339/flask-sqlalchemy-constructor).

Comment: This will depend on how this `gen_password_hash` is defined. If it is defined inside the `SomeModel` class, then you should be able to instantiate the class and then call the method `.gen_password_hash` before committing. But if it is a function defined outside the model, then you want something like `user = SomeModel(name='george', password='whatever'); user.hashed_pwd = gen_password_hash(user.password); db.session.add(user); db.session.commit()`. Also make sure that `hashed_pwd` is a column defined in your model if you've got the second scenario.

Comment: I see. That works. I was hoping to use `__init__` to conveniently wrap all these things, but I get errors saying that I'm working outside of an application context.

Comment: Feel free to share the code that's causing the error and I or someone else here will be happy to have provide a fix. You can definitely use an __init__ to get the password hashed.

Comment: Okay, I've added my attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my interpretation of what you are looking to do. You want to create a static method that converts a given string password into a hashed password. Obviously python's `hash` is not a password hashing function, so I would recommend using something else more consistent and reliable. This hashing method can be used during the initialization of the `User` model inside your application. What this means is that every time you create a user with a username, email and password, that password is hashed first before it is made an attribute of the ensuing `User` object. Take a look at the following for an illustration:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(36))

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = self.generate_pwd_hash(password)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_pwd_hash(pwd):
        """
        This is where you define how
        to hash the user's password.
        """
        return str(hash(pwd))  # This is, of course, not the way to hash a password


db.create_all()

user = User(username='george',
            email='george@example.com',
            password='whatever')

try:
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
except:
    print("This username must already exist.")
```