# Changes to model class's __init__ method don't seem to be taking effect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two particular model classes that are giving me errors during my testing, upon inspecting the methods for each I was pretty certain my issues were the result of typos on my part.

I've made the changes in both classes as needed, but re-running the tests produces the same error. I even tried dropping my schema and re-creating it with Flask-SQLAlchemy's `create_all()` method, but I still run into issues.

In the `Metrics` class, the variables in the `__init__` method were wrong and were missing underscores (Ie: `self.name` instead of `self._name`). I addressed that by changing them to `self._name` and `self._metric_type`

In the HostMetricMapping class, I needed to add the `host_id` parameter to the `__init__` method, since I had forgotten it the first time. So, I added it.

```
class Metrics(_database.Model):



    __tablename__ = 'Metrics'
    _ID = _database.Column(_database.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _name = _database.Column(_database.String(45), nullable=False)
    _metric_type = _database.Column(_database.String(45))
    _host_metric_mapping = _database.relationship('HostMetricMapping', backref='_parent_metric', lazy=True)


    def __init__(self, name, metric_type):
        self._name = name # This line used to say self.name, but was changed to self._name to match the column name
        self._metric_type = metric_type # This line used to say self.metric_type, but was changed to self._metric_type to match the column name


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self._ID)



class HostMetricMapping(_database.Model):



    __tablename__ = 'HostMetricMapping'
    _ID = _database.Column(_database.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _host_id = _database.Column(_database.Integer, _database.ForeignKey('Hosts._ID'), nullable=False)
    _metric_id = _database.Column(_database.Integer, _database.ForeignKey('Metrics._ID'), nullable=False)
    _metric = _database.relationship('MetricData', backref='_metric_hmm', lazy=True)
    _threshold = _database.relationship('ThresholdMapping', backref='_threshold_hmm', lazy=True)


    def __init__(self, host_id, metric_id):
        self._host_id = host_id # This line and it's corresponding parameter were missing, and were added
        self._metric_id = metric_id


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self._ID)
```

The issues I encounter are:

1. When trying to instantiate an instance of `Metrics` and add it into the database, SQLAlchemy raises an `IntegrityError` because I have the `_name` column set to not `null`, and SQLAlchemy inherits the values for both `_name` and `_metric_type` as `None` or `NULL`, even though I instantiate it with values for both parameters.
2. For HostMetricMapping, Python raises an exception because it still treats that class as only having the `metric_id` parameter, instead of also having the `host_id` parameter I've added.

Comment: this might happen if the parent class implements `__new__` or uses metaclasses, which is often the case for ORM

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what would be my work-around in this case? I dropped my schema and re-made it after making a change to file itself, so I don't get where the previous values would be cached / stored that they're still apparently being referenced from

Comment: I would go to the definition of `_database.Model` and check how it is instantiated. However, from this snippet I can't say where it was imported from

Comment: SQLA models use `__init__` as you'd expect. Please provide a [mcve] and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Might be of use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460339/flask-sqlalchemy-constructor

Answer (score 3):

A better way to override `__init__` when using flask-sqlalchemy is to use [reconstructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html). Object initialization with sqlalchemy is a little tricky, and flask-sqlalchemy might be complicating it as well.. anyways, here's how we do it:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor

class MyModel(db.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.init_on_load()

    @reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # put your init stuff here
```

Comment: With this method, will I be able to run different instance of  child class of "db.Model" at different port? Like `connex_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir=basedir)`, `app = connex_app.app`, `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` and then `class Person(db.Moded)`? (entire code at https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api-part-2/)