# Trying to inherit from flask db.Model class -> __init__ not being called

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my flask application I'm trying to inherit from custom flask db.model class to add some simple logic on top of db.model object. Please find details below. I have two questions here:

1. When I instantiate my child-class *Activity* by calling *Activity.query.first()*,  neither *__init__* method of *Activity* class nor *__init__* method of parent *DBActivity* class are being called. I would love to understand why they are not being called and how make them being called.
2. In general, is it a good/viable practice to inherit from flask model classes to implement business logic? If not - would would be a suggested practice?

Appreciate your help a lot!

in app.models I have:

```
...
class DBActivity(db.Model):
    activity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    athlete_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.strava_id'), nullable=False)
    json = db.Column(db.JSON)
    laps = db.Column(db.JSON)
    streams = db.Column(db.JSON)
    df_json = db.Column(db.JSON)
    intervals = db.Column(db.JSON)
    blob = db.Column(db.BLOB)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self):
        print("DBActivity __init__")
```

I also have a following class inheriting from DBActivity:

```
class Activity(DBActivity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('just returned from super().__init__')
        print('running Activity.__init__')
```

Here is how I instantiate *Activity*:

```
with app.app_context():
    a = Activity.query.first()

>>>a
<Activity 5567599209>

>>>isinstance(a, Activity)
True

>>>isinstance(a, DBActivity) 
True
```

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, thanks for pointing this out - this fully solves my question #1. Really appreciate!
Would be nice if you or anyone could share their thought on more general Q#2. Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to @YevhenKuzmovych for pointing to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542650/changes-to-model-classs-init-method-dont-seem-to-be-taking-effect?noredirect=1&lq=1