# Recieving sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError when querying instances of 'Following' object

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
import flask_bcrypt
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

class User(db.Model):
    # __tablename__ = 'user'
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    private = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    bio = db.Column(db.String(300))
    location = db.Column(db.String(300))
    website = db.Column(db.String(300))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='user')
    like = db.relationship('Like', backref='user')
    comment = db.relationship('Comment', backref='user')
    following = db.relationship('Following', backref='user')

    def __init__(self, public_id, name, email, password, admin, private, bio, location, website):  #
        self.public_id = public_id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.private = private
        self.admin = admin
        self.bio = bio
        self.location = location
        self.website = website


class Following(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    following = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('user.public_id'))
    followed = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('user.public_id'))

    def __init__(self, following, followed):
        self.following = following
        self.followed = followed

@app.route('/friends', methods=["GET"])
def get_all_friends():
    friends = Following.query.all()
    return jsonify(friends)
```

I recieve this error when using the friends endpoint: sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.following - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Just as a notice, not relevante to the question, you don't need the init statements, if you dont change any code in there. It is even preferable to not have an init like you do. Here more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460339/flask-sqlalchemy-constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your two ForeignKeys in the 'Following' table are conflicting with each other because they link to the same 'User' table and SQLAlchemy doesn't know which ForeignKey to link with `User.following`. One way to solve this is by adding a 'foreign_keys' argument to the relationships. In your case, you should be able to modify the existing relationship and add a second one. (in your 'User' model)

```
following = db.relationship('Following', backref='user', foreign_keys="Following.following")
followed = db.relationship('Following', foreign_keys="Following.followed")
```

For more information, see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths).